# Clojure - non-looping ways to pick up sequence elements

Tags: clojure, sequence

What are other more clojure-idiomatic ways than looping over a sequence to go through a sequence, and pick up each element from it? This is the loop-version of what i mean:

```
(def a-seq (list 700 600 500 400 300 200 100))

(loop [s a-seq]
    (if (seq s)
        (do (instrument (first s)) (recur (rest s)))
         "End"))
```

I will be feeding the `(first s)` as a frequency into a sin-wave generator as follows (in the overtone lib):

```
(use 'overtone.core)
(definst instrument [frequency 0] (sin-osc frequency))
```

Comment: Use `map` and `for`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` function is what you want to use.

```
(map instrument a-seq)
```

This will call the `instrument` function once for each element in `a-seq`, in order.

Note that map is lazy, so you will need to consume the results of map to guarantee that any side-effects to take place, or call `doall`.

Comment: This is nice! I did this `(map #(do (Thread/sleep (+ 100 (rand-int 401))) (instrument %)) a-seq)` and it just works. What do you mean by **consuming** the results for side-effects?

Comment: If you do something like this: `(do (map instrument a-seq) 1)` then the result will be 1, but instrument might never be called. In your example you are probably in a REPL which prints the result, which causes the lazy sequence returned by map to be realised.

Answer (score 1):

Use `doseq`:

```
(doseq [item a-seq]
  (println item))
(println "End")
```

Comment: I have edited my question, printing isn't a big question actually as i am going to use each element as a frequency. `doseq` is rather for having side-effects, right?

Comment: wouldn't "feed into a sin-wave generator" qualify as side-effect?

Comment: @AmirTeymuri - It's a bit hard to answer this without knowing the transformation you want to apply. Your updated question now does nothing but return the string "End". `doseq` is for applying effects but it seems you want to produce another sequence?